# Solution for the scale factor for a curved universe containing only matter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, integration

In my textbook, Introduction to cosmology by Barbara Ryden, the author gives directly the solution for the following integral if $\Omega_0 > 1$:

$$H_ot = \int^a_0 \frac{da}{[\Omega_0/a + (1-\Omega_0)]^{1/2}}$$

With the substitution (she calls it the solution) $$a(\theta) = \frac{\Omega_0(1 - cos \theta)}{2(\Omega_0 -1)}.$$

I don't understand why exactly this is the right substitution and how she found it.
Is it always the way to solve that kind of integrals?

Comment: *Mathematica* can evaluate that integral (or at least what I think you meant it to be) without introducing $\theta$.

Comment: That was a typo. I made the correction. The author doesn't introduce theta. For reference , the integral can be found in p.88 in the second edition.
I would like to know how she found the solution without using mathematica, since she says that the solution to this integral can be written in a parametric form when $\Omega_0 > 1$. Moreover, is there a reason this post has been downvoted?

Comment: For the functions of a ΩM>1, ΩK=1-ΩM universe see [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/83.html), but to do that by hand would be a bunch of work. For your solution where we have a(θ) instead of a(t) you also need to tell us how your θ relates to t, otherwise that result is useless.

Comment: Maybe that's why she gave the solution without further explanation.
As I said, the author simple say "the solution to this integral is most compactly written in a parametric form. The solution when $\Omega_0 > 1$" and then she gives the $a(\theta)$. Also later, she says that $\theta = 0 $ and $\theta = 2\pi$ is the time elapses between the big bang and the big  crunch.